# Avoid an app using location services killed in background after being stationary for ~15 minutes

Tags: ios, background, cllocationmanager

We have an iOS app that is using location services, and is running happily in the background.  However, we've noticed that the app seems to be reliably killed by the OS after about 15 minutes of the user being stationary.

Does anyone know a way to get around this issue?  We seem to be able to have the app run in the background happily if the user is constantly in motion.  Unfortunately, given the kind of activities we're tracking, being stationary is a common occurrence.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the significant change API or the realtime API?

Comment: real-time API, set to high accuracy

Comment: I don't think your app is being killed then.  Probably suspended.  Apple doesn't want your app sucking the battery down for no reason.  In fact, you might have a hard time convincing them to approve this app depending on what you are doing (so many people on here ask the same question about being rejected due to improper use of location background mode).  The app will be woken up again on the next update as far as I know.  If that is the case then there is nothing you can do about it and you'll have to plan around it.

Comment: Are you allowing updates to be deferred? What 'purpose' have you set for the use of the location manager?